# async syntactic oddity

Tags: rust

Why does Rust allow this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = |x: bool| {
        async {
            return
        }
    };
}
```

But not this? Specifically, the error complains that the branches return different types, when they appear to be exactly the same.

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = |x: bool| {
        if true {
            async {
                return
            }
        } else {
            async {
                return
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:42:13
   |
37 |   /         if true {
38 |   |             async {
   |  _|_____________-
39 | | |                 return
40 | | |             }
   | |_|_____________- expected because of this
41 |   |         } else {
42 | / |             async {
43 | | |                 return
44 | | |             }
   | |_|_____________^ expected `async` block, found a different `async` block
45 |   |         }
   |   |_________- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you write `async { }`, the compiler makes a unique anonymous `Future` type. They will be distinct even if two are syntactically equivalent. This is the same for closures.

So your first snippet is simply returning an object (with an anonymous type), while your second is trying to return different types conditionally, which is not allowed. Consider using a trait object so they are the same type:

```
use std::future::Future;

fn main() {
    let f = |x: bool| {
        if true {
            Box::new(async {
                return
            }) as Box<dyn Future<Output=()>>
        } else {
            Box::new(async {
                return
            })
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can the compiler not recognize the type of a closure? Why does it not treat two closures having the same type as having the same type?

Comment: Different closures are not the same type even if they have the same signature.

Comment: What is the difference between "type" and "signature"? I am familiar with the terms from Haskell.

Comment: @Test Both closures and async blocks essentially cause the compiler to generate `struct`s which contain the captured variables as fields and which `impl Fn(...) for <closure type>` or `impl Future for <async block type>`. They are distinct types just like your own `struct`s are distinct types, even if they _implement the same traits._ The signature of a function is the type of its parameters and return value — that is, the particular `Fn(...) -> ...` trait it implements — but not the type of the function itself.

Comment: But *why* is this the case? If this requirement were relaxed, what would go wrong?

Comment: Since they can capture variables, they can be of any size. The only way to handle things of different sizes in the same type is via indirection (which is achieved above using `Box`). The compiler won't do this for you because it could cause missed optimizations and unnecessary allocations in general usage.